# Reading AVRO messages fails for AWS glue schema registry deserializer

Tags: aws-glue, avro, confluent-schema-registry, debezium, aws-msk-connect

I have built a kafka pipeline using MSK, MSK Connect, Debezium Postgres Source connector and AWS Glue schema registry.
On producer side, I am able to publish AVRO records with schemas in Glue schema registry, I am using [aws glue schema registry library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry) for integration between kafka connect and glue schema registry.
Below is my connector configurations for glue -

```
 # Glue Schema Registry Specific Converters
    "key.converter" = "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter"
    "key.converter.schemas.enable"   = false
    "value.converter"= "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter"
    "value.converter.schemas.enable" = true

    "key.converter.region"                        = "us-east-1"
    "key.converter.registry.name"                 = "<REGISTRY NAME>"
    "key.converter.compatibility"                 = "FULL"
    "key.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled" = true
    "key.converter.dataFormat"="AVRO"
    "key.converter.avroRecordType"="GENERIC_RECORD"
    "key.converter.schemaNameGenerationClass" = "<SCHEMA NAME GENERATION CLASS>"

    "value.converter.region"                        = "us-east-1"
    "value.converter.registry.name"                 = "<REGISTRY NAME>"
    "value.converter.compatibility"                 = "FULL"
    "value.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled" = true
    "value.converter.dataFormat"="AVRO"
    "value.converter.avroRecordType"="GENERIC_RECORD"
    "key.converter.schemaNameGenerationClass" = "<SCHEMA NAME GENERATION CLASS>"
```

On consumer side, I have an EC2 instance. I am using `kafka-avro-console-consumer` command provided by confluent to read the message from AVRO topic. I have also added [aws glue schema registry library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry) JAR in `confluent/share/java/kafka-serde-tools` folder to make it available for the command.
I am using following command -

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server <bootstrap_server_url> \
--consumer.config client.properties \
--property schema.registry.url=https://glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com \
--property print.key=true \
--property print.value=true \
--key-deserializer com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.avro.AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer \
--value-deserializer com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.avro.AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer
--topic platform_avro_users --from-beginning
```

And the consumer config file contains -

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler

key.deserializer=com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer
key.deserializer.region=us-east-1
key.deserializer.registry.name=<REGISTRY NAME>
key.deserializer.avroRecordType=GENERIC_RECORD
key.deserializer.schemaNameGenerationClass=<SCHEMANAME GENERATION CLASS NAME>

value.deserializer=com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer
value.deserializer.region=us-east-1
value.deserializer.registry.name=<REGISTRY NAME>
value.deserializer.avroRecordType=GENERIC_RECORD
value.deserializer.schemaNameGenerationClass=<SCHEMANAME GENERATION CLASS NAME>
```

I am expecting the command to print the messages for me but I get following error -

```
Processed a total of 1 messages
ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$:44)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.GlueSchemaRegistryDeserializationFacade.deserialize(com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.common.AWSDeserializerInput)" because "this.glueSchemaRegistryDeserializationFacade" is null
    at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.avro.AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeByHeaderVersionByte(AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:149)
    at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.avro.AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AWSKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:114)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageFormatter$AvroMessageDeserializer.deserializeKey(AvroMessageFormatter.java:125)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageFormatter.writeTo(SchemaMessageFormatter.java:157)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.process(ConsoleConsumer.scala:116)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:76)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:53)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

Looks like the GlueSchemaRegistryDeserializationFacade class isn't being initilized hence the records are not able to deserialise. I am not sure if I am adding the deserialiser JAR at right place.
Is there a way to fix this issue and read AVRO records when using glue schema registry?

Comment: The error says the class is loaded, to the JAR is fine. I suggest you open this issue at https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry/issues

Comment: I suggest you try with `kafka-console-consumer` since the stacktrace is trying to use `io.confluent.kafka.` classes, but those are not needed to consume from Glue Registry / MSK

Comment: @OneCricketeer, `kafka-console-consumer` does not consider glue schema registry parameters e.g. region, registry name etc. Let me know if there is a way it can be used

Comment: Neither does Confluent's Avro console reader. You'll need to define your own message reader interface, I guess